# group actions (left, conjugation, etc...)

Tags: abstract-algebra

We mentioned in class three important group actions of any group G. Show carefully that each are indeed group actions.

**a-** Left group action $G \circlearrowright G$ where $g \cdot h = gh$ for all $g, h \in G$.

**b-** Conjugation action $G \circlearrowright G$ where $g \cdot h = ghg^{-1}$ for all $g,h \in G$.

**c-** For a subgroup $H \leq G$, the left action of $G$ on $G/H$ where $g \cdot aH = (ga)H$.

----definition----

If we have a group G ($g,h \in G$), a set X ($x \in X$), we can show that $\alpha$ is an action if

$\alpha:G \times X \to X$

i. $e\cdot x$

ii. $g\cdot (h \cdot x)=(gh)\cdot x$

----My attempt----

**a-i.** wts $e\cdot x=x$, but that sounds obvious. How would this ever not happen?

**a-ii.** wts $g\cdot (h \cdot x)=(gh)\cdot x$, but $g\cdot h= gh$ is given. What on earth am I supposed to show?

**b-i.** wts $e \cdot x = x$, but $e\cdot x=exe^{-1}$, so we are done.

**b-ii.** wts $g\cdot (h \cdot x)=(gh)\cdot x$, but $g\cdot(h\cdot x)=g\cdot(hxh^{-1})=ghxh^{-1}g^{-1}=(gh)x(gh)^{-1}=(gh)\cdot x$, so we are done.

**c-i.** wts $e\cdot x=x$, so $(ex)\cdot H=x\cdot H$? Is there not more to this?

**c-ii**. wts $g\cdot (h \cdot H)=(gh)\cdot H$? Isn't it just $g\cdot (h \cdot H)=g\cdot (hH)=ghH=gh\cdot H$?

I feel like I have to be missing something absolutely critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a i) It sounds obvious, because it is. You have $e\cdot x=ex=x$.
a ii) You have $g\cdot(h\cdot x)=g\cdot(hx)=g(hx)=(gh)x=(gh)\cdot x$.

b i) You need to finish it by stating $exe^{-1}=x$
b ii) You have an error. The middle equality should read $ghxh^{-1}g^{-1}$.

c i) You want to show $e\cdot xH = xH$. This is straightforward: $e\cdot xH = (ex)H = xH$.
c ii) You want to show $g\cdot(h\cdot xH) = (gh)\cdot xH$ (remember, the $g$ and $h$ are in the group and $xH$ is in the set). We have

$$g\cdot(h\cdot xH)=g\cdot(hx)H=(ghx)H=(gh)xH = (gh)\cdot xH$$

Answer (score 0):

a-i: As you mentioned, $e*x=ex=x$ is obvious (indeed, by group axiom called identity).

a-ii: This also follows from the group axiom, associativity. We have $g*(h*x)=g*hx=g(hx)=(gh)x=(gh)*x$.

b-i and b-ii: You are correct.

c-i: What you want to show is $e*x=x$ for all $x\in X$, which means $e*gH=gH$ for all $gH\in G/H$. By identity axiom, we get $e*gH=egH=gH$.

c-ii: Again, what you want to show is $g*(h*aH)=(gh)*aH$ for all $aH\in G/H$. This holds by associativity axiom, $g*(h*aH)=g*haH=g(ha)H=(gh)aH=(gh)*aH$.